# downgrading rake version from 10.1.1 to 10.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, database-migration

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
ruby '2.0.0'
```

I am using rails 4 but some how, rake 10.1.1 is installed. So, whenever I fire a command like

`rake db:migrate`

It is giving following error:

```
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.1.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.1.0. Using     bundle exec may solve this.
```

I don't want to write `bundle exec` each time I fire rails commands.

So, any nice solution for this??

Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually,

`gem uninstall rake -v 10.1.1`

and then

`bundle install`

Works for me. [Thanks Ju Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21062228/456814).

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
gem uninstall rake
```

and remove the newer version of the gem.

---

Or add the current version as a binstub with

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
bundle binstubs rake
```

After that, you can use

```
bin/rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply run:

```
bundle update
```

Done!

Comment: but doing that, it will update all gems in gemfile, which is not expected and can break application.